# Windows phone 8 emulator doesn't show map

Tags: maps, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm using Windows Phone 8 emulator for application testing.
I have a screen with Map control but that control shows me only blue background (and red dot which I use for centering the map control). I have checked both ID_CAP_MAP and ID_CAP_LOCATION. Also, I've read [THIS](http://michalstawarz.pl/2013/01/26/windows-phone-8-emulator-maps-display/) solution and still I get that blue screen. Furthermore, I made a change to registry values like [THIS POST](http://igrali.com/2012/07/30/windows-phone-location-tool-in-emulator-down-no-problem/) says, but there are no changes.

I'm behind firm's proxy server and I can open web pages using emulator. Also, when I click chevron button (>>) on an emulator and click on Locations tab I can clearly see maps, but when I run my app the only thing I see on a space that should be map is that blue background screen.

Does anyone know what could cause the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, Windows Phone 8 Emulator has an issue with proxy.
As soon as I "killed" proxy the map showed on the screen, and when I returned using proxy it disappeared.